# How to get Returned Query Object of PostgreSql Function in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

With pgsql function `SelRec(integer)` as defined below:

```
-- select record
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SelRec(_sno integer)
  RETURNS SETOF app_for_leave AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM "app_for_leave" WHERE "sno"=_sno;
    END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

I tried to call this function inside my python code, and expected the returned result as query object which furthermore I could get an individual value inside the query object.

```
import psycopg2

connection_string = 'postgresql://postgres:111111@localhost:5432/myDB'

conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

obj = cursor.execute("select * from SelRec(1)");

conn.commit()

print obj # None
```

Yet, the result is `None` as if there is no data stored, but it does exist like below:

```
 sno | eid | ename |     sd     |     ed     | sid | status 
-----+-----+-------+------------+------------+-----+--------
   1 | 101 |       | 2013-04-04 | 2013-04-04 |   2 | f
```

My need is the `obj` return an query object which I would further call `DataSet = obj.first()`, and `DataSet.status`, ect for each individual value.

Any suggestion how I can achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Ah my bad. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, @jmunsch, the object return as turple, wondering if it is possible to access each value by column name instead of index 0,1,2.. Can we archive that just like using sqlalchemy? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be expected behavior.

From the docs http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute

> The method returns None. If a query was executed, the returned values
>   can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.

Try something like:

```
print(dir(obj), type(obj))
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: Thanks, after I ran command `obj.fetchall()`, I got an exception ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'```. I'm pretty sure my function ` SelRec(1)` return a result when I run it in pgSql `select * from SelRec(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try query given below. As you want to return set of rows.

```
select * from SelRec(1) as result (sno int, eid int, ename varchar, sd data_type, ed data_type, sid int, status boolean)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, does this statement run in Postgresql? I think I need it executed in python code, :)

Comment: If this return set of rows in postgresql then I think it should run in python also with fetchall

Comment: Also get error running in postgresql, ```ERROR:  a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"```

Comment: Does * in select query means all the column stated in `as result` section??

Comment: yeah, * mean select query all columns

Comment: Ya I know that. these (sno int, eid int, ename varchar, sd data_type, ed data_type, sid int, status boolean) are all columns ? try this `select sno, eid , ename , sd , ed , sid , status from SelRec(1) as result (sno int, eid int, ename varchar, sd data_type, ed data_type, sid int, status boolean)`

Comment: yeah, this is for my table `app_for_leave` definition  ```sno    | integer               | not null,  eid    | integer               |  ename  | character varying(20) | , sd     | date                  | ,  ed     | date                  |,  sid    | integer               | , status | boolean   | default false```, :D

Comment: get the same error: `ERROR:  a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"` trying the command above. thanks

Comment: You are returning table, is it necessary? If you change that with record. Than return next record in function. After that run above select query.  Sorry can't help if this doesn't work.

Comment: my expectation is this the function will return the query object which in return I could access each individual column value by column name, something like obj.columName. From jmunsch answer, I could get the query object returned yet it’s in tuple that has to access each value by index number. I want to get it by column name, is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: You are not executing query in postgrsql, not you want in postgrs just to return query??

Comment: Meaning it is not possible I could achieve that expectation. Understand `cursor.execute(query_string)` always return a tuple http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#fetch . Tone of thanks for your help on this :)