# Capture the Postgresql function return string within Python console

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgresql function that returns a string as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION script.fn_indent()
RETURNS character varying
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
------
----function body to perform data insertion job---
results:='0 - Success';
return results
exception when others then
  get stacked diagnostics
      v_state   = returned_sqlstate,
      v_msg     = message_text,
      v_detail  = pg_exception_detail,
      v_hint    = pg_exception_hint,
      v_context = pg_exception_context;
  raise notice 'Transaction was rolled back';
  raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
  results:=v_state||'-'||v_msg||v_msg||'-'||v_detail ||'-'||v_hint ||'-'||v_context;
return results;
```

Now I am trying to run the above function from python using psycopg2.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect({connection string})
curr = conn.cursor
try: 
   curr.execute("SELECT * FROM script.fn_indent())
   conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    err = str(error)
    conn.rollback()
    curr.close()
    print(err)

conn.close()
```

The above code is running fine. But I want to capture the return string from `script.fn_indent()` and show the same to python console. Something like as below:

```
---above python script---
print (results) <--results is the returning string that comes from fn_indent()
```

How to do it? I do not have any clue on this.

Comment: What are actual wand expected outputs?

Comment: I want that the python script shall have `print(fn_indent() return string)` or similar like this.

Comment: If the function just returns a string I would try with '''Select fn_indent()''''?

Answer (score 0):

I got the clue from this thread

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350645/how-to-get-returned-query-object-of-postgresql-function-in-python)

Accordingly, I have modified the code base as follows:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect({connection string})
curr = conn.cursor
curr.execute("SELECT * FROM script.fn_indent()")
conn.commit()
s = curr.fecthone()
print (s)
conn.close()
```